# How to browse git history of images

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a tool (preferably linux/ubuntu) that can be used for browsing history of an image (`.png`, `.jpg`...) file being tracked in git?

Use case:

- user is tracking some image, e.g. database ER model, system performance diagrams (RAM, CPU, ...)
- few years later, the user is interested in seeing how the file changes over the time
- in ideal case each image version contains either a label or link to the commits relevant to the viewed image version
- optionally the tool is able to highlight the areas of the image that actually changed in the viewed version

I know one could create a script that extracts image versions and somehow attaches commit messages to it but I'm looking for an existing solution and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 6):

A simple `git log -- myfile.jpg` will show you any commit where that file is involved.

Check out if a tool like [`ewanmellor/git-diff-image`](https://github.com/ewanmellor/git-diff-image) could help.

It does highlight the area of the image which has changed.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ewanmellor/git-diff-image/master/example-comparison.png]